# Can you pre-order digitally from the Xbox Store?

Tags: xbox-one

I see many new games announced at E3 and earlier up for pre-order on physical disks through the Microsoft Store and other retailers.

However, can I pre-order digital copies of these games from the Xbox Store?

It does not look like it, and I find that really surprising. I do not want the physical disks. They take up too much space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preordering and preloading of digital content are currently not available on the Xbox One, but this is certainly something that Microsoft has been looking at implementing in the future as revealed on their E3 Conference yesterday.

http://au.ign.com/articles/2014/06/10/e3-2014-xbox-boss-gives-update-on-digital-pre-ordering-pre-loading

Answer (score -5):

Of course you couldn't because if you could that would mean getting the game, also they game usually comes out on disk first then digital later on. But sometimes I've seen things like that but only one or two times on different things.

Comment: Preordering a copy digitally is not the same as downloading it. Besides it's something on the horizon for the Xbox One: http://au.ign.com/articles/2014/06/10/e3-2014-xbox-boss-gives-update-on-digital-pre-ordering-pre-loading